# Calculation in Calculated Column not Working

Tags: calculated-column

I am unable to determine why SP keeps kicking back on error on the following.

This is a calculated column that is reading the contents of a CertQualTitle column and applying/returning the appropriate 'Number' based on the CertQualTitle to the 'DaystoRenewal' column.

Example: Firefighter I           0
Medical              1095
Fitness Test          365
Fire Officer II         0

=IF(OR(OR(OR(CQTitle="Medical",1095),CQTitle="Fitness Test",365),CQTitle="Self-Contained Breathing Apparatus Fit Test",365),CQTitle="Live Fire Refresher",720, 0)

Can someone clarify for me why the above won't deliver the desired result, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your **OR**([Col1]="AB", [Col1]="XZ") construct is not correct. Also,  [DaystoRenewal] should be of type **Number**. Let me know if the output doesn't meet your requirements.

Try the below

```
=IF(CQTitle="Medical",1095,IF(OR(CQTitle="Fitness Test",CQTitle="Self-Contained Breathing Apparatus Fit Test"),365,IF(CQTitle="Live Fire Refresher",720,0)))
```

[image]